# Flutter: Location package Not working on First Time App Install

Tags: dart, flutter

My current app uses the Location package ([link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-readme-tab-)) to obtain the user's current latitude and longitude to be used to find nearby facilities.

This is the code I am using (similar to the example in the documentation)

```
  Map<String, double> _currentLocation;
  Map<String, double> _startLocation;

  StreamSubscription<Map<String, double>> _locationSubscription;
  String error;
  bool _permission = false;

  Location _location = new Location();

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  initPlatformState() async {
    Map<String, double> location;

    try {
      _permission = await _location.hasPermission();
      location = await _location.getLocation();

      error = null;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'Permission denied';
      } else if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
        error = 'Permission denied - please ask the user to enable it from the app settings';
      }

      location = null;
    }

    setState(() {
      _startLocation = location;
      print("Starting coordinates: ${_startLocation["latitude"]}, ${_startLocation["longitude"]}");
    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

      initPlatformState();

      _locationSubscription =
          _location.onLocationChanged().listen((Map<String,double> result) {
            setState(() {
              _currentLocation = result;
              print("Current coordinates: ${_currentLocation["latitude"]}, ${_currentLocation["longitude"]}");
            });
          });
  }
```

The only problem I am facing is that whenever there is a fresh install of a new apk of the app, the app does not find the location after location permission has been granted.

[image: Permission Request]

After location has been granted I have set up a print statement to print out the user's location but for some reason it is not printing anything the first time only. After I restart the app then it prints out the location just fine.

**First Time Opening After Install**

[image: First Terminal]

**After Restarting the App**

[image: Second Terminal]

Any experts that use the Location package that could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to plugin’s source code when you invoke `getLocation` method it asks `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` to get required permission and then process. According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) from Google:

> This method functions asynchronously. It returns right away, and after the user responds to the prompt, the system calls the app's callback method with the results

, but flutter plugin has an [issue](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-readme-tab-) about location callbacks for Android 6+ and as a workaround it is recommended to aim SDK 21.

So it seems that “native” part of this plugin doesn’t play well with Android 6+. There are two workarounds:

1. Set SDK to 21 version for your Android project, but I would definitely not recommend doing that.
2. Create some sort of “hello screen”, which will introduce the app and handle permissions there.

Meanwhile, I am really interested in what is wrong with the plugin cause its implementation seems good, so in case I’ll find how to fix it I’ll get back here.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just read on the issue in the repo that some people are facing similar issues with mine. Hopefully we could get a fix for that soon.

Comment: It was complicated to resolve this without major source code changes, so the fix appeared to be a bit dirty. You may follow news about this issue here - https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/pull/84 As far as I see the plugin is not really in active development, so feel free to fork fixed version and use it for your app.

Comment: Sure thing Olexa. I managed to find a workaround to my problem by using the simple permissions package to request permission in the login page and getting the location after logging in. So far it works just fine.